# Speaking program with 4x4 matrix keypad, and getting multiple numbers read

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, keypad

My program uses text to speech and reads numbers and letters that are pressed on a 4x4 matrix keypad attached to raspberry pi. When I press 2 it prints and says "Two"
When I press 22, it currently prints "2" new line "2" says "Two" "Two".
I would like it to have some kind of waiting time, so if you push multiple buttons it reads out "twenty two" "thirty four" "Three hundred and five" etc.

These double or triple digit integers will be later used to pull information from a list of lists. e.g. pushing 22 in the keypad will cause the pi to speak "22! spicy potato chips!" pushing 46*# in quick succession will cause the program to end. Pushing 00 will speak a help message to users.

Here is my current code:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import pygame
from io import BytesIO
import time
from pad4pi import rpi_gpio



KEYPAD = [
    ["1", "2", "3", "A"],
    ["4", "5", "6", "B"],
    ["7", "8", "9", "C"],
    ["*", "0", "#", "D"]
]

ROW_PINS = [5, 6, 13, 19]
COL_PINS = [12, 16, 20, 21]

factory = rpi_gpio.KeypadFactory()
keypad = factory.create_keypad(keypad=KEYPAD, row_pins=ROW_PINS, col_pins=COL_PINS)

def say(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, slow=False, lang='en-us', lang_check=False)
    fp = BytesIO()
    tts.write_to_fp(fp)
    fp.seek(0)
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(fp)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

def printKey(key):
  print(key)
  say(key)

# printKey will be called each time a keypad button is pressed
keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(printKey)

try:
  while(True):
    time.sleep(0.2)
except:
 keypad.cleanup()
```

When I was using tkinter, and keyboard numberpad, someone on stack overflow helped me make this thing called keybuff. But I dont know how to do the same thing with my matrix keypad

```
keybuf = []

def test_after():
           if keybuf:
                      num = ''.join(keybuf)
                      keybuf.clear()




def get_key(event):
           keybuf.append(event.char)
           event.char = ''.join(keybuf)
           root.after(500,test_after)
           if event.char == '-':
                      back()
           elif event.char == '+':
                      forward()
           elif event.char == '.':
                      current()
           elif event.char in vl2: #input a number thats in a list
                      readnumber(event.char)
           elif event.char == '00':
                      help()
```

Comment: Have you tried registering two keypress handlers and concatenating the results?

Comment: I dont even know what that is. I'm just a noob. Plus I don't want to limit myself to 2 digit numbers. for example my function to close the program is a 4 key combo

Comment: How do you think your code might be able to differentiate 22 from 2 then 2?

Comment: When I was using tkinter for number input, someone here helped me making this thing called keybuf, so I could use the numberpad on my keyboard and enter 22, 00, 43 etc.